# Print a list of fields passed as a variable

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a file say `a.txt` and below are the contents of it:

```
bob 1 100            
lincoln 2 200  
chris 3 300
```

The file contents are separated by space.

Using awk, I could access each column. Using below command
to print 1st and 3rd columns separated by comma:

```
cat a.txt | awk ' { print $1","$3} '
```

and I was successful.

Now I want to pass the criteria dynamically from another shell script. By saying criteria I mean - `$1","$3`.

I tried the below command but it didn't work.

```
myvar="$1"   
awk -v a="$myvar"  ' { print a } ' a.txt
```

but this is printing `$1` 3 times as there are three rows in `a.txt`.

How can I pass a list of fields to awk in this way?

Comment: `"$1"` means the first argument of your shell script.  how did you call your script? `script "1"` ? If `a` is `1`, you should print `$a`

Comment: "$1","$3" - this part need to be passed dynamically - along with the delimiters. say, if i have 5 columns, I should be able to send something like $1",$2"-",$3"-"$4","$5  ie 1 & 2, 4 &5  seperated by commas and rest by - .  I will be passing pattern from another file as an argument . and awk command will be on a different file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that the `$` in the variable you have passed to awk is interpreted literally - it cannot be used to refer to a specific field.

For a single field, you could use something like this:

```
awk -v field=1 '{ print $field }' file
bob
lincoln
chris
```

For multiple fields, this is a little more complicated:

```
awk -v fields="1 3" 'BEGIN{ n = split(fields,f) }
    { for (i=1; i<=n; ++i) printf "%s%s", $f[i], (i<n?OFS:ORS) }' file
bob 100
lincoln 200
chris 300
```

The list of fields is passed as a string, which is split into an array. The array is then looped through, using `printf` to output each field, followed by either the Output Field Separator `OFS` or the Output Record Separator `ORS`, depending on whether it's the last field or not.
To separate the fields with a comma, you can pass `-v OFS=,` as an option.

Comment: I am glad that i found answer to my question. Is there any way i can add delimiters to the output in case of multiple fileds.

Comment: Yep, you can set `OFS` to something other than the default space using `awk -v OFS='whatever you want here'`.

Comment: "$1","$3" - this part of the actual question need to be passed dynamically - along with the delimiters. say, if i have 5 columns, I should be able to send something like $1",$2"-",$3"-"$4","$5 ie 1 & 2, 4 &5 seperated by commas and rest by "-" . I will be passing pattern from another file as an argument . and awk command will be on a different file. I am failing to achieve this.

Comment: It seems like you're making things more complicated by trying to find a general solution for arbitrary fields and delimiters. Perhaps it would be a better idea to decide on some specific use cases and implement those. If you have any more problems, it might be better to put them into a new question.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to pass a delimited string to `awk` and inside `awk` use `split` to split on that delimiter.

Something like this should work:

```
awk -v search='1,3' 'BEGIN{split(search, a, ",")}
               {f=""; for (i=1;i in a;i++) {printf "%s%s", f, $a[i]; f=OFS} print ""}' file
```

**Output:**

```
bob 100
lincoln 200
chris 300
```

Comment: Thanks @TomFenech, I have edited it. Somehow `lenght` works for on BSD (osx) awk.

Comment: or capture the length when splitting `len=split(...)`

Answer (score 4):

Alternative to awk solution using `cut` which already accepts field positions via comma separated list.

```
cols="1,3"; cut -d" " -f"$cols" a.txt
```

for comma separated output pipe to `tr ' ' ','`  or use `--output-delimiter=","` cut option.

Note that this will give you the flexibility to specify input as closed or open range such as `1-3` or `2-`