# Get non-monotonically increasing fields in Bash

Tags: bash, cut

Let's say I have a file with multiple columns and I want to get several fields but they may be not in increasing order. Field indexes are in an array, indexes can be in any order or not order at all and the number of indexes is unknown, for example:

```
arr=(1 3 2)   #indexes, unknown length
echo 'c1 c2 c3' | cut -d " " -f "${arr[*]}"
```

The output of that is

```
c1 c2 c3
```

but I want

```
c1 c3 c2
```

So it seems `cut` is sorting the fields before reading them, I don't want that. I am not restricted to `cut`, any other command can be used.

However, I am restricted to this, rather old, version of bash:

```
GNU bash, version 2.05b.0(1)-release (i586-suse-linux)
Copyright (C) 2002 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

**EDIT** Solved thanks to Benjamin W and Glenn Jackman

```
echo "1 2 3" | awk -v fields="${arr[*]}" 'BEGIN{ n = split(fields,f) } { for (i=1; i<=n; ++i) printf "%s%s", $f[i], (i<n?OFS:ORS) }'
```

It is important to reference the array with '*' instead of '@'.

Comment: Version 2.05? Really?

Comment: (Not that the version of `bash` is really relevant here, since you need external tools for this.)

Comment: [This answer using awk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32397022/3266847) looks like it should get you most of the way there.

Comment: To expand the array into a single string, use index `*`  not `@` => `-v fields="${arr[*]}"` -- that uses the first char of $IFS (a space by default) to join the array elements

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not work with bash 2.05:

```
arr=(1 3 2)
set -f                         # disable filename generation
while read line; do
    set -- $line               # unquoted: taking advantage of word splitting, 
                               # store the words as positional parameters
    for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
        printf "%s " "${!i}"   # indirect variable expansion
    done
    echo
done < file
```

Or, perl

```
$ cat file
c1 c2 c3
$ perl -slane '
    BEGIN {@a = map {$_ - 1} split " ", $arr} 
    print join " ", @F[@a]
' -- -arr="${arr[*]}" file
c1 c3 c2
```

Comment: How about using `read -a` to avoid glob expansion in the first place? It seems to have been around since Bash 2.0.

Comment: I don't have an old bash, and didn't feel like poking around in the historical docs for read -a. However, I think it would add more complexity than what I have: read -a creates an array with 0-based indices, so you'd have to add some arithmetic to the array parameter expansion. On the other hand, I wouldn't have to turn off filename generation.

Comment: Ah, true, I forgot about the indexing. I thought "I'll just spin up a Bash 2.05 docker container to test it", but the [official repo](https://hub.docker.com/_/bash/) doesn't go further back than 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
$ arr=(1 3 2)
$ echo 'c1 c2 c3' | awk -v arr="${arr[*]}" '
    BEGIN {
        split(arr, idx," ");
    } 
    {
        for(i=1; i<=length(idx); ++i) 
            printf("%s ",$idx[i])} ;
    END {
        printf("\n")
    }
'
```

1. First, split `arr` by `' '` and assign to idx
2. Then, print based on each index `i`

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
$ cat file
a b c d
a b c d
a b c d
a b c d

$ awk -v ord="1 4 3 2" 'BEGIN { split(ord, order, " ") }
                        {
                            split($0, line, FS)
                            for (i = 1; i <= length(order); ++i)
                                $i = line[order[i]]
                            print
                        }' file
a d c b
a d c b
a d c b
a d c b
```

The order is given by the `ord` variable passed on the command line.  This variable is assumed to hold as many space-separated values as are available in the input file.

In the `BEGIN` block, an array, `order`, is created from `ord` by splitting it on spaces.

In the default block, the current input line is split into the array `line` on `FS` (whitespace by default).  The fields are then rearranged according to the `order` array and then the re-constructed line is printed out.

No test is made that the passed-in value in `ord` is sane. If the input has *N* columns, it must contain all the integers from 1 to *N* is some order.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract your read from your print so you can name the parts and order them accordingly.

```
$: cat x
c1 c2 c3
c1 c2 c3
c1 c2 c3
c1 c2 c3
c1 c2 c3
$: cut -f 1,3,2 x |
> while read a b c
> do printf "$a $c $b\n"
> done
c1 c3 c2
c1 c3 c2
c1 c3 c2
c1 c3 c2
c1 c3 c2
```

This puts the read loop into the bash interpreter, which isn't as fast as a binary, but doesn't require another tool that you were already using.

I don't see much point in using awk if you have perl, so if the file is big enough you need a faster solution, try this:

```
perl -a -n -e 'print join " ", @F[0,2,1],"\n"' x
```

Assumes a lot, and adds a space before the newline, but should give you a working place to start.

Comment: I left the `cut  -f 1,3,2` since it just pulls them without reordering anyway.